# How to bring bottom UITableviewcell to the first row of Accordion style UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accordion

I was trying to create an **accordion style table view**. I have achieved my target but at the bottom of UITableviewcell the data is hiding while expanding the cell. I just needed to pull the particular cell to the first row of tableview to make show all the data visible. Now it happens only user scroll the tableview up but I need it while selecting on the tableviewcell to bring it to the first row as I said above. Can anyone assist me on this please asap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your TableView scroll to a particular row. Just put the following into your **didSelectItemAtIndexPath**-method:

```
[self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here I just wanted to bring my bottom last UITableview cell to show as the first cell while selecting it, meaning all other top cell has to go up automatically like the user do scroll up manually. Since in accordion view each cell would contains some data that has to be expanded to listing without scroll up by the user. Please advice.

Comment: I'm sorry, in this case I don't understand your question.

Comment: Ok, Are you sure it is didSelectItemAtIndexPath-method? I couldn't find any method as you mentioned. To be direct question. Can I pull my bottom UITableviewcell scroll up to top of the tableview automatically without scroll manually by didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Ok now I get what you mean. The code above will scroll the tapped row to the top (defined by UITableViewScrollPositionTop) and not the bottom one. You have to calculate the index of the bottom row and then give it into the scrollToRowAtIndexPath:
And yes, this method is available on a UITableView-object (are you developing for iOS7?)